# error on converting string to date in java

Tags: java, date, string-to-datetime

`2014-04-23T18:30:00.000Z` need to convert in this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:sszzz` in java

I am using this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.zzzZ");
Date newfromDate = new Date();
try {
    //Convert into date 
    newfromDate = (Date)formatter.parse(fromDate);

    // get required Format of date in string format 
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:sszzz");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but this is not working

error :-  `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-03-31T18:30:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try  this

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX").parse(s);
```

or this

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2014-04-23T18:30:00.000Z");
```

the last version is supposed to be faster (no need to parse pattern) and thread-safe